# Accessing spray request from spray response

Tags: asynchronous, akka, spray, spray-client

I'm calling this function **every 50 ms** :

```
def send() = {
    val myData = generateRandomData()
    val response = pipeline(Post("http://slow-website.com/send", myData))
    response onComplete {
      case Success(r) => ? how to access myData  ?

      case Failure(error) => print(error.getMessage)
    }
}
```

I would like to know what data was sent in my successfull request.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just refer to `myData`.

What happens behind the scenes is that the Scala compiler creates a closure for the `onComplete` handler argument that captures the reference to `myData` so that you can use it.

Comment: Easy & Simple... I done that many times in nodejs. I don't know why I didn't think the same may. Thanks